# Is there a way to read inserted row before transaction commit with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have a PDO transaction, using PHP and MySQL that inserts a row into the database.
Inside the same transaction I should read the inserted row to insert another row.
All inside the same transaction.

I've read about READ UNCOMMITED isolation level here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted

Is it possible to set SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL to READ UNCOMMITTED only for the current transaction?

Or there is a better alternative?

UPDATE:

Here's a resumed example for clarification:

The first inserted row is a sale order, with the following fields:

saleOrderId (auto-increment)

customerId

saleOrderTotalAmount

The second inserted row is a sale order item, with the following fields:

saleOrderItemId (auto-increment)

saleOrderId (generated in the first inserted row)

itemQuantity

itemAmount

After the second row is inserted, an update is executed to change saleOrderTotalAmount from the sale order.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you need from the inserted row that means you need to read it back?

Comment: Hello @NigelRen. I've updated the question for clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just set `saleOrderTotalAmount` to `itemQuantity * itemAmount` when inserting into the sale order table, rather than updating after the second insert?

Comment: Because I also need to get saleOrderId from the first inserted row to insert as foreign key into the second insert.